# css images center without stretching images

Tags: css

I want my images center without stretching images.
I'm using display block, got this snippet from stackoverflow but it doesn't work.
My code:

```
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
    float: left;
    width:  100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-size:     cover;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<section class="customer-logos slider">
   <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="/images/brand/1.png" alt="Image"></a></div>
   <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="/images/brand/2.png" alt="Image"></a></div>
   <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="/images/brand/3.png" alt="Image"></a></div>
</section>
```

I'm using slick slider.

Added html code

[Images center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS8bk.png)

Comment: Can you post your HTML? It seems like you're trying to treat inline `<img>`s as though they're `background-image`'s.

Comment: You mean vertically?

Comment: My slider works but images are not in center.

Comment: You are aware, I hope, that the `HTML` code you have posted above, is not using the `CSS` rules you also posted above? You have defined rules for `class slick-slide` and you are using `class slide`. In addition, you have an `<a></a>` tag surrounding your images, which might be messing up your layout, if there is a definition for it in one of your style-sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, all you really need is to display the images as `inline-block` and then set vertical alignment.

```css
.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-slide">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x30" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is since you never explained what happens, only what you want to happen. Is this live somewhere?

Comment: If i use only your css code then all images are big so I use width:100%; but images not going center.

Comment: I think he's working with the slick carousel plugin: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @Faceit well, you can see that my snippet works. You must have other css overriding it.

Comment: @Faceit I would need to see your page live in order to investigate.

Comment: My images are different sizes all the time. So it needs to be center. I tryed JS centerMode: true, but it doesnt do anything...

Comment: You could put together a proper snippet or fiddle.

Comment: @Faceit I commented out one line in the middle of your css and I added a new declaration at the very top: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooZwgW

Answer (score 0):

*This should work*

Well...all the magic is done in .slick-slide
You transform the image into the blocked element...And then you say centralize it. margin: 0 auto;
You can set the margin property to auto to horizontally center the element within its container.

The element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the left and right margins

See: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

```
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0 20px; 
}

.slick-slide img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span style="height: 100px"></span>
  <span></span>
  <span style="height: 50px"></span>
</div>
```